# compiling kernel for raspberry with xenomai patch

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, xenomai

I have a problem when I compile my old kernel 3.2 when I add xenomai patch.

This is the error that come always:

```
Makefile:492: recipe for target 'silentoldconfig' failed
make[1]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 2 HOSTCC arch/x86/tools/relocs make: *** 
No rule to make target 'include/config/auto.conf', needed by 'include/config/kernel.release'. Stop.
```

Comment: Just throw away ancient crap.

Comment: yes it work when i throw away ancient crap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i use a kernel from this setion https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux rpi.4.4.y of kernel and it works

Comment: can you share what patch you are using?

Comment: i used xenomai-3.0.2